# Entity framework, map oracle database type number(10) to .net Int32

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

The field in oracle database with type `number(10)`, which is larger than .net `Int32` range.
I'm now using entity framework to fetch data from this table, and map it to database entity of this table. But, I got this error when I fetch the data:

```
var competitions = db.PKG_API_PORTAL_SP_GETFBCOMPETITION().ToList();
```

> The type of the key field '' is expected to be 'System.Int32', but
>   the value provided is actually of type 'System.Int64'.

I found this question [Oracle Data Provider to CLR type mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684460/oracle-data-provider-to-clr-type-mapping)

and here is the article to explain how the datatype been translated
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/DataTypeMapping.html

But now I need a solution to solve this problem.

Comment: I second this question. I would hate to manually modify emdx etc.

Comment: have you tried declaring the key field where you store it explicitly as int 64?

Comment: did you consider using a view to map number(10) to another datatype (i.e. number(8) or similar)?

Comment: If this a Stored Procedure then you create a complex type and then modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming since you're using DotConnect For Oracle with EF that you are returning a Refcursor from the function/SP that's being projected to a datatype.

You have three options to fix the problem:
1- Change the Type in the Object you are mapping to an Int64. This is the easiest solution. If you're using entity developer, just select the type in your mapping, change the type to 'int64', click OK, regen your classes.

2- Change the Refcursor being returned to downcast the number(10) to a Number(9). This will probably hurt performance, and will eventually break something, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Every column of type NUMBER(n) represents an INT64. 
"n" acts as a constraint for the table, but all data in it is the same size. 
You'd better move to an Int64 type in the client side.
Cheers!